# Enable WAMP/phpmyadmin designer/relationview

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using wamp 2.4e 32bit on windows8

I have followed these two articles..

#### [Enable Dessigner in WAMP](http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/enable-designer-tab-in-phpmyadmin/), [Enable RelationView visualization](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/enable-designer-phpmyadmin/)

. 2nd one seemed better one to me.

I have successfully created phpmyadmin database as instructed. Also I think the path where I am puting the server configuration is also ok. i.e **wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\config.default.php**

But still unable to get designer/relation-view tab. Before today I had executed same process successfully on windows7, and older wamp versions many time. **Might be some issue of windows8 or wamp version**. But I want it better to be fixed in same scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of libraries/config.default.php, there is a big warning against modifying this file. You should only modify config.inc.php (top directory).

After a change in config.inc.php regarding the configuration storage (pmadb)

#### 1. Restast your wamp

#### 2. Close and open your browser

.

Comment: Thanks as your answer solved my problem. I just restarted my browser (my fault i forgot to do) and its working now. Please edit your answr as just to restart browser. I was damm sure it works with changes in wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\libraries\config.default.php as it is working.

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit config.default.php as this file might change with each version; that's why you should only change config.inc.php.